# I tried to PHP Server: Serve but it doesn't start

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xampp, wamp

Today, out of blue when I tried to serve my php file, it didn't work anymore. When I press serve the console output:
[Tue Feb 13 10:32:10 2024] PHP 8.0.30 Development Server (http://localhost:3000) started.
But when I try to reach that url, it says this:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.0.30 Server at localhost Port 80

I have reinstalled everything, but it keep doing the same thing.

Comment: `http://localhost:3000` and then : *"Server at localhost Port 80"*... Use just `http://localhost`

Comment: I was just about the say the same thing - firstly make up your mind which webserver you're intending to use. Also... XAMPP _and_ wamp? Again...make up your mind. And neither of those is related directly to VS Code or to the PHP development server. It _sounds_ like maybe VS Code is configured to start the PHP development server, rather than to go to your Apache server URL, but it's all a bit vague in your description.

Comment: ADyson I always used wamp, but when I tried everything, I uninstalled it and I tried with xampp, but it doesn't work neither. In fact, even when xampp or wamp isn't up, visual studio code still says the server is running

Comment: `visual studio code still says the server is running`...probably because it seems to be trying to use the PHP built-in development server on port 3000, as the message indicates. It would likely make more sense if you simply opened your regular `http://localhost` URL as we mentioned earlier - assuming Apache is configured to serve files from the relevant directory. This really has nothing to do with the difference between XAMPP and WAMP anyway...they both install Apache, which is what is actually used to serve files and execute PHP.